# Limiting distributions identified as functions of Brownian motion or stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, asymptotics

I am teaching a stochastic processes course to MA stat students, and to stay on topic I would like some examples of limiting distributions in stat that are identified as functions of brownian motion or stochastic integrals.  I have thought of kolmogorov-smirnov & dickey-fuller,  neither of which uses stochastic integration.  Examples have to be short, especially, not require lots of stats backround.

Comment: I think you might be interested in the martingale central limit theorem.